# Why does a promise inside setTimeout resolve before a subsequent setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

Run the following code in browser or node.js:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(1);
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(2);
  });
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(3);
});
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be 1 3 2?

Comment: First off, if you want a specific ordering of asynchronous operations, then you should write the code to guarantee it and not rely on the inner scheduling details of different parts of the event loop.  Second, resolved promises have a higher precedence in the event loop than timers.  Third, understanding the entire ordering of event loop processing is a very involved and complicated thing and thus should not be relied upon for normal coding.  Instead, sequence your async operations with code in the desired order rather than rely on this level of even loop behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Promise callbacks and timer callbacks are scheduled differently from each other.

Promise handler functions are called asynchronously at the end of the task that scheduled them. You're scheduling two tasks (the timer callbacks). In the first task, since the promise is already fulfilled, the callback to the fulfillment handler happens asynchronously at the end of the task (it's a so-called *microtask*). Then the next task (the next timer callback) happens.

So your code executes like this:

1. The task for executing your script runs:

   1. It schedules the timer callback for the first `setTiemout`.
   2. It schedules the timer callback for the second `setTiemout`.
   3. The task ends
2. The task for the first timer callback runs:

   1. It does `console.log(1)`
   2. It creates a fulfilled promise
   3. It attaches a fulfillment handler to that promise

      1. Since the promise is already fulfilled, this schedules a microtask to call the handler
   4. The task ends
   5. The microtask queued by the task runs, doing `console.log(2)`
3. The task for the second timer callback runs:

   1. And logs `console.log(3)`

For browsers, you can find the details of this process in the [Event Loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops) section of the specification.

It's worth noting that microtasks scheduled during a microtask run in the same "clear out the microtask queue" step as the microtask that scheduled them, *before* the next (macro)task runs. Consequently, the following gives us `1 2a 2b 3` rather than `1 2a 3 2b` as you might otherwise expect:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1);
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("2a");
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("2b");
    });
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(3);
}, 0);
```

as does this (because it's largely the same thing):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1);
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("2a");
        Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            console.log("2b");
        });
    });
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(3);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE WITH DIAGRAMS :**

Yes, that's because `Promise.resolve()` has a different `queue` called the **JOB QUEUE or MICROTASK QUEUE**, and this `Job Queue` has the higher Priority than the `Callbacks Queue`. Note that we are dealing with Promises now and not the callbacks when we do Promise.Resolve ! So Javascript ES6 came up with this Job Queue to handle Promises differently and call backs differently :)

So, **Event Loop** is going to check the `Job Queue first` and make sure there is nothing in that Queue before it starts looking, at the `Call back Queue`. So that the Job Queue has higher Priority than the call back queue.

[image: The JOB QUEUE]

I want to give an example to make it more clear because I feel that will make it explain more clearly.

```js
setTimeout(()=>console.log("This is line 1"));

Promise.resolve("Two").then(data=>console.log("I am ",data));

setTimeout(()=>console.log("I am third"));
```

In the above code snippet, Promise is resolved first  and only then the other setTimeout. That's because of the